# JQ: Select when attribute value exists in a bash array

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, vpc, jq

I'm using jq 1.4.
I trying to select elements when VPCZoneIdentifier exists in my `$selected_subnets` (bash variable).

```
selected_subnets="valueA valueB"

input='{"elements":[
           {"name": "nameA", "VPCZoneIdentifier": "valueA"}, 
           {"name": "nameB", "VPCZoneIdentifier": "valueB"}, 
           {"name": "nameC", "VPCZoneIdentifier": "valueC"}
       ]}'
```

`test` and `match` fn are only available on v1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little tricky, but it can be done with `reduce`. The whole thing could look like this:

```
selected_subnets_json=$(echo "\"$selected_subnets\"" | jq -c -M 'split(" ")')
echo "$input" | jq -M '.elements = [.elements[] | select(.VPCZoneIdentifier as $id | '"$selected_subnets_json"' | reduce .[] as $v (false; . or $id == $v))]'
```

The first part makes a JSON array from the shell list:

```
$ echo "\"$selected_subnets\"" | jq -c -M 'split(" ")'
["valueA","valueB"]
```

The second part uses the `reduce` filter to compare the `.VPCZoneIdentifier` property with all elements of this array. With the `selected_subnets_json` variable expanded into it, the filter looks as follows:

```
.elements = [
  .elements[] |
    select(.VPCZoneIdentifier as $id |
           [ "valueA", "valueB" ] | reduce .[] as $v (false; . or $id == $v))
]
```

That is to say, the `elements` property is overwritten with those elements of it that match the selection criterium

```
.VPCZoneIdentifier as $id | [ "valueA", "valueB" ] | reduce .[] as $v (false; . or $id == $v))
```

Of this the first part remembers the `VPCZoneIdentifier` as `$id` (because `.` will shortly mean something entirely different), and

```
[ "valueA", "valueB" ] | reduce .[] as $v (false; . or $id == $v))
```

is an or-reduction of the subnet array. It expands to `false or $id == "valueA" or $id == "valueB"` in this case.

If you prefer to have it all in one go, you could write

```
echo "$input" | jq -M '.elements = [.elements[] | select(.VPCZoneIdentifier as $id | ("'"$selected_subnets"'" | split(" ")) | reduce .[] as $v (false; . or $id == $v))]'
```

This works essentially the same way, except the splitting of `$selected_subnets` is done inline.

Answer (score 4):

You can set variables from the command line to be available in your queries using the `--arg` option.  You can then filter out the elements using the `select` filter.  Given an array of values, you could do a `"value in array"` test doing the following:

```
value == (array[])
```

So your filter would have the following structure:

```
.elements | map(
    select(
        .VPCZoneIdentifier == ($subnets | split(" ")[])
    )
)
```

Putting it all together with your variables:

```
$ echo $input | jq --arg subnets "$selected_subnets" '.elements | map(select(.VPCZoneIdentifier == ($subnets | split(" ")[])))'
[
  {
    "name": "nameA",
    "VPCZoneIdentifier": "valueA"
  },
  {
    "name": "nameB",
    "VPCZoneIdentifier": "valueB"
  }
]
```