# jq: select when any value is in array

Tags: json, jq, any, set-intersection, negation

Given the input json

```
[
  {"title": "first line"},
  {"title": "second line"},
  {"title": "third line"}
]
```

How can we extract only the titles that contain keywords that are listed in a second "filter" array. Using a shell variable here for instance:

```
filter='["second", "third"]'
```

The output in this case would be

```
[
  {"title": "second line"},
  {"title": "third line"}
]
```

Also, how to use the array filter to negate instead.
Eg: return only the "first line" entry in the previous example.

There is a [similar reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142185/jq-select-when-attribute-value-exists-in-a-bash-array) but using an old version of jq.
I hope that there's a more intuitive/readable way to do this with the current version of jq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `jq` and shell tricks using arrays to produce the filter. Firstly to produce the shell array, use an array notation from the shell as below. Note that the below notation of `bash` arrays will *not* take `,` as a separator in its definition. Now we need to produce a regex filter to match the string, so we produce an alternation operator

```
filter=("first" "second")
echo "$(IFS="|"; echo "${filter[*]}"
first|second
```

You haven't mentioned if the string only matches in the first or last or could be anywhere in the `.title` section. The below regex matches for the string anywhere in the string.

Now we want to use this filter in the `jq` to match against the `.title` string as below. Notice the use of `not` to negate the result. To provide the actual match, remove the part `|not`.

```
jq --arg re "$(IFS="|"; echo "${filter[*]}")" '[.[] | select(.title|test($re)|not)]' < json
```

Comment: The use of `test()` is the key here. Thanks for also adding that clever way to parse a shell array and pass the result as input.

Comment: @Alkaline - Please note that jq's `test` is based on regex matches, whereas the original question calls for keyword matches. In general, using `test` naively can give very different results compared to string-based keyword matching.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve a problem that involves the word "any" is often to use jq's `any`, e.g. using your shell variable:

```
jq --argjson filter "$filter" '
  map((.title | split(" ")) as $title
      | select(any( $title[] as $t
                    | $filter[] as $kw
                    | $kw == $t )))' input.json
```

### Negation

As in formal logic, you can use `all` or `any` (in conjunction with negation) to solve the negated problem.  But don't forget that if you use `not`,
jq's `not` is a zero-arity filter.

```
jq --argjson filter "$filter" '
  map((.title | split(" ")) as $title
      | select(all( $title[] as $t
                    | $filter[] as $kw
                    | $kw != $t )))' input.json
```

### Other approaches

The above uses "keyword matching" as that is what the question specifies, but of course the above jq expressions can easily be modified to use regexes or some other type of matching.

If the list of keywords is very long, then a better algorithm for array-intersection would no doubt be desirable.