# jq: select when values from another array match value in this json

Tags: json, regex, bash, jq

Given json:

```
[
  {
    "path": "Module1/",
    "users": [
      "john",
      "jane"
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "Module2/",
    "users": [
      "mike",
      "mary"
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "Module3/",
    "users": [
      "billy",
      "bonny"
    ]
  }
]
```

Given array of files:

```
[
  "Module1/file.java",
  "Module3/file.java"
]
```

**How can I get the users for which any of the files match the path?**

Expected output:

```
[
  "john",
  "jane",
  "billy",
  "bonny"
]
```

I recently found this answer to a similar question, which cleverly builds regex filter and passes as arg in jq:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630000/8784215

I set up similarly:

```
users='[{"path":"Module1/","users":["john","jane"]},{"path":"Module2/","users":["mike","mary"]},{"path":"Module3/","users":["billy","bonny"]}]'
files='["Module1/file.java","Module3/file.java"]'
filter=($(echo $files | jq -r  '. | join(" ")'))
echo $users | jq --arg re "$(IFS="|"; echo "${filter[*]}")" '[.[] | select(.path | test($re)) | .users[]]'
```

But the problem is that path is being matched against file, when it should be the other way around.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ìnside` to flip arguments for a `contains` test which performs a substring matching. Use `any` to select on first match, and `input` to read the second input (array of files):

```bash
jq 'input as $f | map(select(any(.path | inside($f[]); .)).users[])' input.json files.json
```

```json
[
  "john",
  "jane",
  "billy",
  "bonny"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/44R5XS47ZqZ)